# Python - Compare 2 different output formats - Logic

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, diff

I have a programming case which has stumped me. I'm not necassarily looking for code - I'm looking for logic advice, for which I'm at a loss.

I've tried several different things but nothing seems to really formulate concretely.

This is for a regression test. I have two files with the same data in two very dissimilar formats. I need to compare the data and automate the process. I'll worry about the 'diff' at a later stage. It should not be too hard if I can arrive at data from both files which can be compared.

File 1 has essentially JSON data. There is other garbage in the file but that can be removed. This is what data looks like:

```
{
"Chan-1" : [ {
"key1" : "val1",
"key2" : val2,
"key3" : val3,
}, {
"key1" : "val1",
"key2" : val2,
"key3" : val3,
} ]
}
```

File 2 has essentially what I can decipher as a python list with items. Each item has data which is in a `key=value` format, separated by commas, in parenthesis.

```
[
spacecraft.telemetry.channel(key1=val1,key2="val2",key3=val3),
spacecraft.telemetry.channel(key1=val1,key2="val2",key3=val3)
]
```

Each block in one file corresponds to the one in another, and essentially if going to be diff'd. So in other words:

```
{
"key1" : "val1",
"key2" : val2,
"key3" : val3,
}
```

from File 1 will (or should) have the same key value pairs as File 2:

```
(key1=val1,key2="val2",key3=val3)
```

The order is also similar.

Both files contain a plethora of key value pairs for the "Chan-1" object, and I truncated the amount of data for example sake. There are about 16 key value pairs in each block, and there are about 400 blocks.

I've tried working on File 2 to make it look like JSON data.
I've tried working on File 1 to make it look more like File 2.
I also tried parsing both files as a 3rd format altogether.
But I've not gotten far with either concept - and something tells me I'm missing something, that this should not be this hard, considering we already have one file in JSON.

I would really appreciate if someone can give me some advice on the Logic to follow here - what appears to be the best route, and what kind of logic should be put in making this happen.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd parse both and add the key-value pairs into some sort of database for checking (or just output as `key:value`, sort those and use `diff(1)`on the results).

Answer (score 2):

For each file:

- extract the 'list' of objects
- convert each object in the list into a dictionary

  - for file 1, this step is basically 'convert JSON into dict'
  - for file 2, this would involve extracting just the `key=value` strings, splitting on `=`, and turning the result into a dict via dictionary comprehension.

At this point, you have two lists of dictionaries.  Your question *seems* to indicate that you can assume the lists are ordered in the same manner, so now you can check that each dict in one list matches the dict in the same position in the other list.  Check out `zip(list_1, list_2)`; it should make this step easier.

Comment: That seems like a logical approach. I know I did the JSON into dict, but  I think I had some trouble with file 2 being a list of dictionaries. You've given a good direction though - I'm going to give this another shot. Thanks.